# Can't understand result of distributive conditional types

Tags: typescript

Why is the result here

```
type result = (1 | 1 | 2) extends 1 ? 3 : 4
```

**4?**

Should not result be 3 | 4 ?

Because I thought above is same as: `(1 extends 1 ? 3 : 4) | (1 extends 1 ? 3 : 4) | (2 extends 1 ? 3 : 4) = 3 | 3 | 4.` No?

Comment: distribution only happens on generic types. `(1 | 1 | 2)` is not a generic type

Comment: `(1 | 1 | 2)` is not a naked type parameter, therefore this is not a distributive conditional type; it is just a conditional type.

Comment: @kaya3 I will check this but what would result be here `type AnyOf<T extends readonly any[]> =  T[number] extends false ? false: true
` if say there are two `false` values and two `true` values in the `T` array?

Comment: `T[number]` is also not a naked type parameter; it is an indexed access type.